# Regex pattern not working properly

Tags: html, regex

I'm working on a simple check for my input fields. I got 3 places where I'm validating user-input: javascript regex, html pattern and php regex. The Javascript and PHP part work fine, but my HTML pattern somehow returns an error for *every* input *except* blank. I tested it on regexpal.com (regex tester) and it works perfectly fine there, so I reckon I must be doing something wrong.

Here's my regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\!\?\,\.\s]{0,50}$/
```

I'm trying to allow users to input the following:

- Alphabetic characters, including capitals
- Numeric characters
- Puncation: exclamation(!), question(?), comma(,) and dot(.)
- Spaces

Here's how I implement it:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" aria-required="true" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\!\?\,\.\s]{0,50}$/" value="loaded value from db">
```

Please note: I'm allowing 0 characters to be entered because I will check it with PHP, and if the input field(s) is/are empty, a pre-set value will be written to the database.

Basically it should allow users to enter general words or sentences, but somehow it doesn't allow anything. The only way I don't get an "error" is when I leave the inputfield blank. What am I doing wrong? Is my regex wrong? Am I not implementing it correctly? I can provide more code if necessary.

Help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I wrong or is quoting only necessary for `-` withing character sets? I mean, shouldn't it just read `/^[a-zA-Z0-9!?,.s]{0,50}$/`.

Comment: Escape \ within the string `\\!\\?` to ensure the regex contains them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the forward slashes (/) from the input's pattern attribute.

Comment: Why did I not notice this before? Rookie mistake on my side, but thanks for your help anyways!